# What is the syntax for specifying dependency versions in Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

So far I have seen three...

```
[dependencies]
crate = "1.0.0"  # I think this is an exact version match
crate = "^1.0.0" # I think this means "use that latest 1.x.x"
crate = "*"      # I think this means "use the latest"
```

I'd love to know for certain how to use the dependency list. It would be nice to have an authoritative source that documents the different syntaxes for dependencies.

Comment: I don't think this question should be down-voted: the documentation on this is *not* in an obvious place.  I pretty much checked every other page of documentation on `crates.io` because I looked at the correct one just to be exhaustive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See the [`crates.io` documentation page on "Specifying Dependencies"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html).  To summarise:

- Nothing or a caret (`^`) means "at least this version, until the next incompatible version".
- A tilde (`~`) means "at least this version, until (but excluding) the next minor/major release".  That is, `~1.2.3` will accept `1.2.X` where *`X`* is at least 3, `~1.2` will accept `1.2.*`, and `~1` will accept `1.*.*`.
- A wildcard (`*`) means "anything that looks like this".  That is, `1.2.*` will accept `1.2.anything` (`1.2.0`, `1.2.7-beta`, `1.2.93-dev.foo`, etc. but not `1.3.0`).
- Inequalities (`>=`, `>`, `<`, `=`) mean the obvious: the version Cargo uses must satisfy the given inequality.