# What does a caret version constraint mean in Rust Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm implementing Rust Cargo version requirements. In general, I have trouble understanding *caret requirements* as specified. I found [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224), but this question is about npm version requirements of which I'm not sure if it is the same as Rust Cargo version requirements.

At https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#caret-requirements, I read:

> Caret requirements allow SemVer compatible updates to a specified version. An update is allowed if the new version number does not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the major, minor, patch grouping. In this case, if we ran `cargo update -p time`, cargo should update us to version `0.1.13` if it is the latest `0.1.z` release, but would not update us to `0.2.0`. If instead we had specified the version string as `^1.0`, cargo should update to `1.1` if it is the latest `1.y` release, but not `2.0`. The version `0.0.x` is not considered compatible with any other version.

> Here are some more examples of caret requirements and the versions that would be allowed with them:

> ```
> ^1.2.3  :=  >=1.2.3, <2.0.0
> ^1.2    :=  >=1.2.0, <2.0.0
> ^1      :=  >=1.0.0, <2.0.0
> ^0.2.3  :=  >=0.2.3, <0.3.0
> ^0.2    :=  >=0.2.0, <0.3.0
> ^0.0.3  :=  >=0.0.3, <0.0.4
> ^0.0    :=  >=0.0.0, <0.1.0
> ^0      :=  >=0.0.0, <1.0.0
> ```
>
> This compatibility convention is different from SemVer in the way it treats versions before `1.0.0`. While SemVer says there is no compatibility before `1.0.0`, Cargo considers `0.x.y` to be compatible with `0.x.z`, where `y ≥ z` and `x > 0`.

I'm confused about

> In this case, if we ran `cargo update -p time`, cargo should update us to version `0.1.13` if it is the latest `0.1.z` release, but would not update us to `0.2.0`.

With what version requirement is this the case? It seems left out of the sentence. It continues to refer to a seemingly missing caret version requirement:

> If instead we had specified the version string as `^1.0`, cargo should update to `1.1` if it is the latest `1.y` release, but not `2.0`.

In which it refers to `>1.0` as the version string (which I miss in the sentence before).

If I dissect the examples, my reasoning is as follows:

```
^1.2.3  :=  >=1.2.3, <2.0.0 // same as >=1.2.3 AND 1.*
^1.2    :=  >=1.2.0, <2.0.0 // same as >=1.2 AND 1.*, which condenses into 1.2.*
^1      :=  >=1.0.0, <2.0.0 // same as 1.*
^0.2.3  :=  >=0.2.3, <0.3.0 // same as >=0.2.3 AND 0.2.*
^0.2    :=  >=0.2.0, <0.3.0 // same as 0.2.*, which condenses into 0.2.*
^0.0.3  :=  >=0.0.3, <0.0.4 // huh
^0.0    :=  >=0.0.0, <0.1.0 // same as >=0.0.0 AND 0.0.*
^0      :=  >=0.0.0, <1.0.0 // same as >=0.0.0 AND 0.*, which condenses into 0.*
```

So except for my understanding of the 6th example (`^0.0.3`), my conclusion is that caret version requirements are exactly as wildcard version requirements, except when PATCH is specified in which the wildcard version requirement ANDs with the `>= {version}` (equal or later then) comparison version requirement.

Is this understanding correct and why is example 6 as it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike in npm, the default version requirement range is indeed the caret requirement! This is stated in the [Cargo reference on "specifying dependencies"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html), just before the section linked in the question.

> The string `"0.1.12"` is a semver version requirement. Since this string does not have any operators in it, it is interpreted the same way as if we had specified `"^0.1.12"`, which is called a caret requirement.

As such, the following two dependency specifications are equivalent.

```
time = "0.1.12"
```

```
time = "^0.1.12"
```

This, by the way, is the requirement referred to in the rest of the document. An update of `time` could bring in a version higher than 0.1.12, but never 0.2.0 or higher.

See also:

- [How to specify the exact version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224563/how-to-specify-the-exact-version-of-a-dependenc)

Comment: Ah, off course - that solves the missing version requirement. What about example 6?

Comment: That would be another edge case of the caret requirement. It is made explicit in the text which you have quoted: _"The version `0.0.x` is not considered compatible with any other version."_