# Why is Rocket's `Json` type not found in the `content` module?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

Today I found that a project that previously worked no longer compiles. Here is a minimal example that reproduces my sudden error:

```
use rocket::{get, launch, routes};
use rocket::response::content;

#[get("/health")]
pub fn health() -> content::Json<String> {
    content::Json("ok".parse().unwrap())
}

#[launch]
async fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/actuator", routes![health])
}
```

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `Json` in module `content`
 --> src\main.rs:5:29
  |
5 | pub fn health() -> content::Json<String> {
  |                             ^^^^ not found in `content`
  |
help: consider importing this struct
  |
1 | use rocket::serde::json::Json;
  |

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `Json` in module `content`
 --> src\main.rs:6:14
  |
6 |     content::Json("ok".parse().unwrap())
  |              ^^^^ not found in `content`
  |
help: consider importing this tuple struct
  |
1 | use rocket::serde::json::Json;
  |
```

I am using `cargo 1.59.0 (49d8809dc 2022-02-10)` and `rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)`. And here are my dependencies:

```toml
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
```

The `content::Json` is supposed to come from Rocket and should be enabled by the cargo feature above. It definitely worked the past. What should I do to fix this problem? How did this happen?

Comment: Try `content::RawJson(...)` instead of `content::Json(...)`. Looks like this changed in 0.5.0-rc.2.

Comment: It seems the `content` module has changed between release candidates: compare [`0.5.0-rc.1`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/response/content/index.html) and [`0.5.0-rc.2`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/response/content/index.html). In `rc.2` you want [`rocket::serde::json::Json`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/serde/json/struct.Json.html) or you can [lock the dependency to a specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224563/how-to-specify-the-exact-version-of-a-dependency) with `"=0.5.0-rc.1"`.

Comment: But I did not upgrade the rocket version, I am still using 0.5.1.@Dogbert

Comment: Are you sure? Inspect the lock file.

Comment: I finally found out the lock the vision of rocket should add = in the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `content` module was changed between Rocket release candidates. Compare the documentation for [`0.5.0-rc.1`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/response/content/index.html) and [`0.5.0-rc.2`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/response/content/index.html). The `Json` type moved to [`rocket::serde::json::Json`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/serde/json/struct.Json.html). So your code should look like this:

```
use rocket::serde::json::Json;

pub fn health() -> Json<String> {
    Json("ok".parse().unwrap())
}
```

> But I did not upgrade the rocket version, I am still using 0.5.0-rc.1

It seems you did, albeit unknowingly. This can happen if `cargo update` was ran or you simply didn't preserve your `Cargo.lock` file (or something recreated it). It is somewhat dubious if `rc.1` should be seen as compatible with `rc.2`, but regardless, you can *lock* your dependency to a specific version by prefixing it with `=` if you want to stay on `rc.1`:

```toml
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "=0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
```