# How to resolve a "cyclic package dependency" error?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've built a simple app with these dependencies:

```toml
[dependencies]
core-foundation = { version = "0.9", features = ["with-chrono"] }
```

With `cargo 1.62.1 (a748cf5a3 2022-06-08)`. My platform is a Macbook Air M1 (the target might matter, not sure).

And I'm getting this error:

```
error: cyclic package dependency: package `chrono v0.4.21` depends on itself. Cycle:
package `chrono v0.4.21`
    ... which satisfies dependency `chrono = "^0.4"` of package `core-foundation v0.9.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `core-foundation = "^0.9"` of package `iana-time-zone v0.1.42`
    ... which satisfies dependency `iana-time-zone = "^0.1.41"` of package `chrono v0.4.21`
```

If I clone `core-foundation` and build it myself using `cargo build --features="with-chrono"`, I'm not getting any error.

Any idea how to investigate this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do if the cyclic dependency occurs with crates you don't control. You could attempt to "fix" one of the crates by cloning and modifying it to avoid a problematic dependency and [override](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) your dependencies with the fixed version.

Your best bet is to notify the maintainers of the crates involved. If the issue only arose recently, you can try [locking your dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224563/how-to-specify-the-exact-version-of-a-dependency) to an earlier version as a workaround.

---

This particular issue seems to be resolved already. It likely happened when `chrono` added `iana-time-zone` as a dependency in version 0.4.21. However, the fix was for `iana-time-zone` to change its dependency from `core-foundation` to `core-foundation-sys` in version 0.1.45 to break the cycle.